# How can I add a keyboard to password component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces3.5 and I want to add a password field with a virtual keyboard for my login page, any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Keyboard component, with mode `password='true'`

```
<p:keyboard value="#{keyboardBean.value9}"  
                    password="true" />
```

**See also: [Primefaces keyboard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/keyboard.jsf)**